# DIV Floating To The Left Instead Of Staying In The Center Of The Table

Tags: html, css

I am working on a table within a web page. the table contains a grid of 4 boxes in td tags. I employed the use of a 3D flip transition in my CSS stylesheet for the boxes. The issue i have is that when i apply the CSS to a div within a column (td), the image that had been aligned to the center moves to the left. I tried setting margin-left and then right, of the div to auto, but still nothing. I'd provide part of my HTML and CSS and also the screenshot of the issue. Please help in resolving this -

PS: For some reason, i'm trying to paste my HTML code, but it's not formatting right.

[image: Screenshot of the webpage]

HTML:
        
                  [image]
                  
                    
                        -->
                            -->
                                
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                    This Is The Back!
                                
                            -->
                        -->
                    
                  
                  
                    
                         Payment Log

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
/**width: 320px;
height: 480px;**/
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;

}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
z-index: 2;
/* for firefox 31 */
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so add text-align center in image parent div

like this:

```
td{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to align text to the center. i'm trying to align the image to the center. text as it is already align to the center, the image just doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
 background: #ccc;   
}
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can see example in http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/GDdtS/

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained how the code works.

Comment: As i replied above, i'm trying to align the image to the center, not the text.

Comment: but you add text-align center in your image parent image is align center

Comment: Jenti, i added align="center" to the td column housing the div with the image in it. It does align when there's no CSS, but when I add CSS properties of the divs to it, the images shifts to the left

Comment: If you access the url example and you insert an image instead of text, you will see that is always aligned to the center, without any offset    http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/9341/